# Why might SRS indicator light continuously?

Tags: honda, civic, supplemental-restraint-system

After a trip to the beach, the SRS indicator in my 2003 Honda Civic is lit continuously.  I don't think I have side airbags.  A somewhat wet person sat in the passenger seat, and I moved the driver seat forward and backward to its extremes trying to find something under it.  What might have caused this change?  It hasn't come on before in the 4 months that I've owned it.

Is it possible to read out a trouble code with the OBD, or is that just for Check Engine lights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't read it just like the check engine light.  There is a different procedure.

This website does a great job outlining the procedure and has a translation for the codes:
http://forums.clubrsx.com/showthread.php?t=636707

Looks like you should try to follow there instructions to reset the SRS.  If that doesn't work follow the instructions and images to read the main and sub codes.

Comment: I think I'd try to read the code first, and then try to reset it.

Comment: The code is 7-2 "Internal failure of SRS unit".  I will "check battery/system voltage" and try resetting it.

Comment: Resetting it worked

Comment: It's come back several times, though.  Same code each time I've read it.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem with my 2005 Honda Civic; it just lit up all of a sudden. The thing is, the buckle gets stuffed with dirt over a certain period of time. I tried resetting (using paper clip technique) it a couple of times but no luck.
So i got this CRC contact cleaner spray can and tried to squirt it in the driver side buckles, then tried to reset it again and the light went off.
So in conclusion, honda's seatbelt buckles are not dirt resistant which affects the SRS connection. Honda should improve this sensitive part of their SRS, it should be protected from dirt and all sorts of dust which makes the SRS fail.

Comment: This should probably be on http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1912/31 instead of here.