# SRS indicator light keeps coming on, code 7-2 "Internal failure of SRS unit"

Tags: supplemental-restraint-system

As in [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/why-might-srs-indicator-light-continuously), my SRS light keeps coming on.  I read the code using a paperclip in the OBDII connector, which is always code 7-2 "Internal failure of SRS unit", and then reset it using the SRS connector.  It stays off for weeks or months and then comes back on.  Any idea how to troubleshoot this?  Or do I have to take it to a mechanic?  Obviously messing around with airbags is dangerous if you don't know what you're doing.

2003 Honda Civic

Comment: Remember that "dangerous" in this case is defined to be "quite easily fatal."

Comment: @BobCross: Yes.  Then again, so is driving.

Comment: The dangers are not equivalent.  A explosive expansion of the airbag impacting an unexpecting person at close range and at an off angle from the design is a probable neck snapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually just bit the bullet and let the dealership replace the SRS unit for several hundred dollars.  Light hasn't come back on since.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, unless you know anyone that can help you with the troubleshooting, I would take it in. Depending on your vehicle [Not mentioned], it could be any of a ton of sensors [depending on age] in the vehicle. Seat Occupancy can do it, Door pressure sensors can do it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced an 8-3 code which is another internal failure of the SRS unit code. From my research, a low battery can bring about an internal failure code.  Apparently, before you replace the air bag control module, you should make sure that your battery and charging system is up to par.  If everything checks out and you still can't erase the code, chances are you will have to replace the control module.  I got mine for about fifty bucks on Ebay.  The dealer will charge you close to 600.

I have read codes on many civics by shorting 4 and 9 terminal with no adverse affects.  I have never had an airbag go off, although I keep myself out of harms way due to airbag neck snapping rumors spread by dealerships who want to charge you for a 5 minute diagnostic test on their scanner.

Comment: oh you replaced the module yourself? where is it?

Comment: Yep, they want $600 to replace the control module, and charged $100 for the scan, but then say they will take $100 off the $600 if I bring it back to them to fix.